# to set custom error redirect in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, sfguard

I am using Symfony 1.4 with Propel as ORM. I Have created a login system for my frontend page, where user can login and edit there account details.The page is set with Permission ="user" and Group ="user". But on loging in with a user which doesnot belong to this group, redirects to the symfonys default page(showing user dont have credentials to view this page). 
can these pages be customized and set our own custom messages..and how can we set custom error pages??

the code that i have used,

```
if($this->getContext()->getUser()->hasCredential("user"))
{
    $user_name=$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getUsername();
    $this->name=$user_name;
}
else
{
    $this->forward("userlogin", "error");
}
```

but i dont know this is the best way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change templates by overwriting them in Your app:
`apps/<appname>/modules/default/templates/error404Success.php`

To see list of possible templates look at:
`lib/vendor/symfony/lib/controller/default/templates/`

Now about credentials. At file `apps/<appname>/config/settings.yml`:

```
# ...

all:
  # ...

  .actions:
    login_module:           sfGuardAuth   # Change this to whatewer You want.
    login_action:           signin        # Change this to whatewer You want.

    error_404_module:       default       # Change this to whatewer You want.
    error_404_action:       error404      # Change this to whatewer You want.
```

So if You want to change just template -- change just template. But if You want something more powerful -- change `settings.yml` and write custom code.

Comment: actually this is not working! i had made the action(error404Success.php) in the module and set configuration to error_404_module:      mymodule and error_404_action: error404. but not working...it is redirected to the default one..

Comment: got the problem, actually i was checking in Dev mode and hence it was not showing me the Custom Error page!...

Answer (score 0):

You should watch the logs to see why it doesn't find your 404 action, what it's looking for, etc.

Comment: ok, i will look into it...is it any thing tobe done in the Route file??